# Unsupported operand type for %: 'file' and 'unicode'

Tags: python, unicode

I'm trying to scrape a bunch of census data about my area, starting with just the one link to get the code right.  I want to, initially, get the heading of the    page and store the data in the page in a txt file named after what the heading is.

So for instance in this case, `Census Block 970900-1-001 in Cortland County, New York` would be the title of the txt file.  However, when I try to do this using the `% variable` method, it gives me the error `Unsupported operand type for %: 'file' and 'unicode'`.  I understand the error message - my question is, how can I achieve the functionality I'm going for, or is it even possible?

Code written so far:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib2 import urlopen

links = ['http://www.usa.com/NY0239709001001.html']

def block():
    link = links[0]
    html = urlopen(link)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html.read(),'lxml')
    h1 = soup.find('h1').text
    print(h1)
    f = open('%s.txt','w') % h1
    f.write(h1)
```

**Expected Output:**
Creation of a file titled `Census Block 970900-1-001 in Cortland County, New York.txt`

**Actual Output:**

```
Unsupported operand type for %: 'file' and 'unicode'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm guessing you want:

`open('%s.txt' % h1, 'w')`

i.e. you want to use string formatting to generate the filename to pass to `open` -- You don't want to open a file named `'%s.txt'`.

Comment: D'oh! Thanks, @mgilson!

Comment: @n1c9 -- Happens to the best of us.  The trick is to learn how to read the traceback carefully.  I can't tell you how many hours of my life I've wasted tracking bugs that would have been easy to find if I just read the traceback a little more carefully . . .

Answer (score 2):

Put the `% h1` inside the `open()`:

```
f = open('%s.txt' % h1, 'w')
```